# my SQL Like query in spaced variable

Tags: php, mysql

In My table postcode insert a `ZE2 9EE`  space between the post code .

In user search , enter correct format postcode `ZE2 9EE` it will work fine in `LIKE` query . But if the user enter postcode without space `ZE29EE` LIKE query is not working .

The below query is not working .

```
$pcode='ZE29EE';
SELECT * FROM postalscheme  where Postcode LIKE '%$pcode%'
```

Comment: Perhaps `where replace(Postcode,' ','') like ...`

Comment: your query was working fine which it was supposed to do. ` ZE2 9EE` and `ZE29EE` are not same. so it will not give you what you expect. In order to achieve it you have to use `replace()` as mentioned in previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM postalscheme 
 WHERE REPLACE(Postcode, ' ', '') 
   LIKE '%" . str_replace(" ", "", $pcode) . "%'"
```

This will match your codes regardless on how many and where user places spaces.

Also, you should definitely escape user input to avoid [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) attack.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM postalscheme  where replace(Postcode,' ','')  
LIKE '%$pcode%' OR Postcode LIKE '%$pcode%'
```

This way your query will work even if the user type a space inbetween or not

Comment: there is no need for `OR Postcode LIKE '%$pcode%' ` because ` replace(Postcode,' ','')` will cover that case

Comment: @krishna what if the passed value have a space?

Comment: hmmmm . ya thought OP  doesn't need that. Anyway its a good thought to pinpoint :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` like below :

```
SELECT *
FROM postalscheme
WHERE REPLACE(Postcode, ' ', '') LIKE '%$pcode%';
```